# Clipping images using BezierPath and combining the images after clipping

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I want to develop a small Jigsaw puzzle game but having problem when combining the image pieces. I can split image but cannot combine them as per my requirement. Here is what I am doing.

For cropping:

```
[customImageView setImage:[self cropImage:self.mainImage withRect:mCropFrame]];


- (UIImage *) cropImage:(UIImage*)originalImage withRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([originalImage CGImage], rect)];
}
```

For Clipping:

```
[self setClippingPath:[pieceBezierPathsMutArray_ objectAtIndex:i]:view];


- (UIImageView *) setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath : (UIImageView *)imgView;
{
    if (![[imgView layer] mask])
    {
        [[imgView layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];
    }

    [(CAShapeLayer*) [[imgView layer] mask] setPath:[clippingPath CGPath]];
    return imgView;
}
```

For Combining:

```
-(id)initByCombining:(id)oneView andOther:(id)twoView withRegularSize:(CGSize)pieceSize;
{
    CustomImageView *one = oneView;//[oneView copy]; 
    CustomImageView *two = twoView;

    CGPoint onepoint, twopoint;
    if (one.frame.origin.x < two.frame.origin.x)
    {
        onepoint.x = 0;
        twopoint.x = onepoint.x + one.frame.size.width;
    }
    else
    {
        onepoint.x = onepoint.x + one.frame.size.width;
        twopoint.x = 0;
    }
    if (one.frame.origin.y < two.frame.origin.y)
    {
        onepoint.y = 0;
        twopoint.y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        onepoint.y = 0;
        twopoint.y = 0;
    }


    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin      = CGPointZero;
    frame.size.width  = onepoint.x + one.frame.size.width + two.frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = MAX(one.frame.size.height , two.frame.size.height);

    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size);

        [one.image drawAtPoint:onepoint];
        [two.image drawAtPoint:twopoint];

        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIGraphicsPopContext();
        self.center = one.center;
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(incomingTransform, 0.5, 0.5);
        self.previousRotation = self.transform;
    }
    return self;
}
```

My initial image is this:
[image]

After cropping and clipping it becomes like this:
[image]

It should look like this after combining.
[image]

But it is becoming like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When You want to combine the Images I would suggest you to place the Clipping within another UIView , so that the UIView becomes a SuperView of all the Placed Clippings, after the Images have been Placed you can do something like this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(superView.bounds.size, superView.opaque, 0.0);

[superView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * CombinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return CombinedImage;
```

and Then just save it as follows..

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

```
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[CombinedImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[SAVEIMAGE imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            // TODO: error handling
            UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Error saving image, Please try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [al show];

        } else {
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(CombinedImage);
           UIImage *finalImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

}

..Hope this helps